# When the adverb “however” is used to introduce a contrary statement, does it have to be followed by a comma?

Tags: word-usage

When the adverb “however” is used to introduce a contrary statement, does it have to be followed by a comma?

I know in such usage, "however" usually accompanies with a comma, but still I found an exception here:

> [The director said he was looking for girls six and up, because he didn’t think that someone younger would be able to act. **However when he saw Wallis act**, he knew he had found the perfect person to play Hushpuppy. He said she was “beyond anything we’d seen before.”](http://teachingkidsnews.com/2013/01/22/1-nine-year-old-up-for-best-actress-oscar/)

Is that an accidental error, or the use of "however" without a comma does exist in some nonstandard English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example sentence, a comma is appropriate after the 'however', so the sentence contains an error.  This is because "when he saw Willis act" is a complete phrase, which should be set off by commas.  If you removed that phrase, the sentence would stand on its own:

> However, he knew he had found the perfect person to play Hushpuppy.

But to answer your broader question, 'however' is generally followed by a comma in a sentence except in the situation Buster described above.

Answer (score 1):

However is overwhelming followed by a comma regardless of the situation. However, when it precedes an adjective/adverb such as short, long, reluctantly, good, temporary, etc. it does not need a comma.

The truth is, you can usually find an instance that goes against the norm. But most people (supported by corpus data) would put a comma in that sentence you cited.

Comment: Thank you. Good explanation, but still, I should say however, preceding an adjective/adverb is a different usage from what my question is talking about...